# Merging non-zeros, non-overlapping elements from two lists in Perl

Tags: regex, list, perl, merge

I'm looking for a clean method in Perl to merge a collection of
lists. The all have the same length, and each consists mainly of
zeros, but also has short contiguous segments of non-zero
entries.  For example, here are two representative lists of
length 25:

```
@flags1 = qw( 0  0  0  0 21 22 23  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 41 42 43  0  0  0  0  0  0  0);
@flags2 = qw(11 12 13  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 31 32 33  0  0  0  0  0 51 52  53 0);
```

The objective is to merge the elements of @flags2 into @flags1 for all the places
where a contiguous clump of non-zero elements in @flags2 replaces
only zero entries in @flags1.  If there is an overlap with any of
the non-zero elements of @flags1, the associated contiguous clump
of non-zero values in @flags2 is discarded instead of being
merged.

Thus, for the example above, the contiguous clump of values 31,
32, and 33 in @flags2[13..15] are discarded because one of the
entries, $flags2[15] is non-zero and collides with the non-zeros value at $flags1[15].  The resulting desired merged list
would be:

```
@merged = qw(11 12 13  0 21 22 23  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 41 42 43  0  0  0 51 52  53  0);
```

I have experimented with collecting up contiguous elements of
non-zero elements into a list of lists, and then comparing them
using for and if statements, but it's a mess, and I think it will
be difficult for any other developer to understand the logic.  If
anyone could propose an more elegant solution that would be much
appreciated.

Comment: Please add the messy solution you tried.

Comment: Clear and interesting question. (I voted to reopen.) I invite readers to translate the following Ruby solution to Perl. `a = flags2.each_index.chunk { |i| flags2[i] != '0' }.filter_map { |keep, arr| arr.first..arr.last if keep } #=> [0..2, 13..15, 21..23]; a.each { |r| flags1[r] = flags2[r] if flags1[r].uniq == ["0"] }; flags1 #=>  ["11", "12", "13", "0", "21", "22", "23", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "41", "42", "43", "0", "0", "0", "51", "52", "53", "0"]`. Operate on a copy of `flags1` if `flags1` is not to be mutated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```perl
use List::Util qw( none );

my $s = 0;
while (1) {
   # Find start of next clump.
   ++$s while $s < @flags2 && !$flags2[$s];

   # Exit if at end of array.
   last if $s == @flags2;

   # Find end of clump.
   my $e = $s+1;
   ++$e while $e < @flags2 && $flags2[$e];

   # Merge in clump.
   my @clump = $s .. $e-1;
   if ( none { $_ } @flags1[ @clump ] ) {      # Or `!grep { $_ }`
      @flags1[ @clump ] = @flags2[ @clump ];
   }

   $s = $e;

   # Exit if at end of array.
   last if $s == @flags2;
}
```

---

This is another approach that is akin to the merge portion of a merge sort.

```perl
sub get_next_clump {
   my ( $f, $s ) = @_;
   ++$s while $s < @$f && !$f[$s];
   return if $s == @$f;
   my $e = $s+1;
   ++$e while $e < @$f && $f[$e];
   return $s, $e;
}

my $ok1 = my ( $f1_s, $f1_e ) = get_next_clump( \@flags1, 0 );
my $ok2 = my ( $f2_s, $f2_e ) = get_next_clump( \@flags2, 0 );

while ( $ok1 && $ok2 ) {
   if ( $f2_s < $f1_e && $f2_e > $f1_s ) {
      $ok2 = ( $f2_s, $f2_e ) = get_next_clump( \@flags2, $f2_e );
      next;
   }
   
   if ( $f1_s < $f2_s ) {
      $ok1 = ( $f1_s, $f1_e ) = get_next_clump( \@flags1, $f1_e );
   } else {
      @flags1[ $f2_s .. $f2_e-1 ] = @flags2[ $f2_s .. $f2_e-1 ];
      $ok2 = ( $f2_s, $f2_e ) = get_next_clump( \@flags2, $f2_e );
   }
}

while ( $ok2 ) {
   @flags1[ $f2_s .. $f2_e-1 ] = @flags2[ $f2_s .. $f2_e-1 ];
   $ok2 = ( $f2_s, $f2_e ) = get_next_clump( \@flags2, $f2_e );
}
```

Comment: I've tested your first solution, and it works well.  It's also, for me, the simplest to understand. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is workable, it just needs some organization. Let's take it a step at a time:

```perl
sub to_ranges {
  my $in = shift;
  my (@ret, $in_range);
  for my $i (0 .. $#$in) {
    if ($in->[$i]) {
      if ($in_range) { # Extend an existing range
        $ret[-1]{end} = $i;
        push @{$ret[-1]{values}}, $in->[$i];
      } else { # Start a new one
        push @ret, { start => $i, end => $i, values => [ $in->[$i] ] };
        $in_range = 1;
      }
    } else {
      $in_range = 0;
    }
  }
  # Dummy entry to make sure the output will be padded to the right length
  push @ret, { start => scalar @$in, end => scalar @$in, values => [] };
  return \@ret;
}
```

This turns a list into a list of "chunks", each of which knows its start, end, and the values it contains. (`end` is not strictly necessary but it makes things tidier).

```perl
sub from_ranges {
  my $in = shift;
  my @ret;
  for my $r (@$in) {
    push @ret, 0 while $#ret < $r->{end};
    splice @ret, $r->{start}, $r->{end} - $r->{start} + 1, @{ $r->{values} };
  }
  return \@ret;
}
```

This does the reverse transformation: `from_ranges(to_ranges(\@x))` should contain the same elements as `@x`.

```perl
sub overlaps_any {
  my ($r, $ll) = @_;
  for my $l (@$ll) {
    return 1 if $r->{start} >= $l->{start} && $r->{start} <= $l->{end};
    return 1 if $r->{end} >= $l->{start} && $r->{end} <= $l->{end};
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This is a helper that returns true if the range `$r` overlaps any of the ranges in `@$ll`.

```perl
sub merge_ranges {
  my ($ll, $rr) = @_;
  my @rr_new = grep { !overlaps_any($_, $ll) } @$rr;
  return [
    sort {
      $a->{start} <=> $b->{start}
    } @$ll, @rr_new
  ];
}
```

And this takes two sets of ranges, `@$ll` and `@$rr` and returns all of the ranges in `@$ll` plus the ranges in `@$rr` that don't overlap. The `sort` is actually only for ease of debugging; you can just `return [ @$ll, @rr_new ]` if you prefer.

```perl
sub merge {
  my ($ll, $rr) = @_;
  return from_ranges(
    merge_ranges(
      to_ranges($ll),
      to_ranges($rr),
    )
  );
}
```

put the pieces together, and [it works](https://tio.run/##hVRdb@IwEHzPr5ijUZXoQoVDeaJFPNy/oAilYILvTJJzkqIK5bdz6w8Sl17vFIHi3fXszHqciis5u1zamqNulNg280C/nzJViCKv50FQt69oyo3KipzXOAfA8R2hKPCM@iD2tMFEoqXiTaITtjTW8X2pbDWiCR4eEN5RPjYggNgjouV4sQrF@hrsww6lDwMhNViN2frMi11H3UMx73NVWx@wPPclb5lsed11hpDtcC3uwCUpPN/sNezPNIRMNXhe0L4E1Oj6agH1ajVAYo1u4NCTJm6s7xb8padfObGVuk7/7vCjPdLIeNGod5o7jtkvOppWcTQHjrJtqrbBSUiJV44q2@34TpfppBL5oYHkRd4cgq901dtMZgpL4tAL/BDzlDp5BNGqAi8aax501hJ7VR7/awq7Y/CBIpt4DvAYTnA6CMnJIbTEE5WOF@ag7XjqSootd7UmZwR1yVCIsZ/Ad7CEHGFjzg5WTveVpPKNLkNW1ZuseL9qikJFPaSMSdly42uRWotOWC0OkWn/@jwWZFQ5LO/vP2SfXHZQ@gnHaPsCxeRuMTx9k17bkauc35xXRPT1ANUgzpyZ2hT8RKFc8Yqs882fSxRu3Dw68otSnj9W9qRK8llv9MyXSjfptV@7e7E0HFxPiq0/Mv4HVdfV82FkMH2lkePRf780Tpx8jhKwjcb0HxsOehR7meU1o5a/TxFZ1D4pQ5oinfaB6/PI8Jji8SZBaD1UaqEYA0vBPiPoZ8owTTH1kzOGWYrZ1IBVShQNfpaiiEYYGY8bydGLo5vAvaV0SHGC0Usxml8ufwA).

ikegami has provided an overall simpler soluion, but I'll still offer up this one because maybe you have other things you need to do that would benefit from this representation.

Comment: Nit: For sorted inputs (which they are), `merge_ranges` can be done in O(N). For unsorted, in O(N log N). But it's currently O(N^2).

Comment: @ikegami okay, yeah, I agree. I would just stick a "maybe optimize later" comment on it.

Comment: @ikegami (if you want to really nitpick, it's O(nm) but could be O(n+m))

Comment: Yes, but n and m are ultimately the same here, so I kept things simple

Comment: I've tested your code, and can see that this works, but the Perlish dialect is too arcane for me to understand.